# How to deep copy in initialization List incase of const variable

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I know deep copy in constructor can be done in following way.

```
class student{
    public:
    int age;
    int rollno;
    char *name; 
    
    
     student(int rollno,int age, char *name){
        this->age=age;
        this->rollno=rollno;


        //deep copy 
        this->name=new char[strlen(name)+1];
        strcpy(this->name,name);
    }
 };
```

But I wanted to do it using initialization list (in case variables are of const type) This is my new class:

```
    class student{
       public:
        const int age;
        int rollno;
        const char *name; // used pointer to avoid wastage of space or less space getting assigned 
      
        student(int age,int rollno, char *name): rollno(rollno),age(age),name(name){
            
        }
    };
```

Now I Am accessing this class in following way

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include "student.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(){

 
    char name[]= "jerry";
    student s(12,1,name);
    cout<<s.name<<endl; //gives jerry
    name[0]='m';
    cout<<s.name<<endl; // gives merry
}
```

So what i want is that object variable's value should not change. it means it should print jerry in both cout statement. There is similar question but I am not getting that or how to implement in this particular case.

Comment: As a quick heads up, `const` member variables are very headache-inducing for limited benefits. Making the members private instead will save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `std::string` to store strings.

With it, your class looks like this:

```
class student{
   public:
   const int age;
   int rollno;
   const std::string name; 
  
   student(int age, int rollno, std::string name): 
     rollno(rollno), age(age), name(std::move(name)) {}
};
```

Not only does this give you exactly what you want, but on top of that:

- By using RAII, it also fixes memory leaks present in your original code
- This will make your code faster and use less memory when dealing with small strings due to some fancy optimizations being done in `std::string`, so even your "avoid wastage of space" concerns are being addressed.

Comment: Thanks its works fine now, and memory leak was something I never realized. In this case we were able to avoid trouble by using string but  what if we were to use initialize list for  int array pointer in the constructor with deep copy.

Comment: @SuryanshSingh Then you would use `std::vector<int>` instead of `int*`. You should never use `new`, apart from some fairly exotic circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use strings? I think that would fix this problem.